# Why variable not renders on page?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have following thymeleaf snippet:

```
    ...
    <p>///////</p>
    ${userName}
    <p>///////</p> 
    ...
```

And I have followinf controller:

```
GetMapping(value = {"/main"})
    public String showPersonsPage(Model model) {
        // don't fill models here. All data got via web socket's subscription.
        model.addAttribute("userName", startupHouseKeeper.getUser().getUserName());
        return "main";
    }
```

But on page I see:
[image]

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inteads of `${userName}` use:

```
[[${userName}]]
```

Always surround variables with square brackets if they are outside of a HTML tag. Below solution without additional brackets:

```
<p th:text="${userName}"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Output your variable using:

```
<p th:text="${userName}"></p>
```